# Regex for extracting only first game out of multiple game PGN file (chess)

Tags: regex

I have a PGN that consists of text like below. I want to extract just the first game, so everything up until the second [Event] tag using regex. My attempts at regex101.com seem to fail over multiple lines, even though multiple line tag is on. For example:

```
\[Event.*\n*
```

Captures only the first line

Any help appreciated.

Edit:
The given answer `\A\[Event.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[Event).*)*` works perfectly, but I have come across a pgn file that breaks the regex as such. I have deleted the old example and put the new one. There is a tag that is `[Eventdate "2009.12.09"]` for example, so now the regex needs to find for the next occurrence of `[Event ...` that isn't `[Eventdate`

Example pgn file:

```
[Event "Hastings"]
[Site "Hastings ENG"]
[Date "1895.08.17"]
[Round "10"]
[White "Wilhelm Steinitz"]
[Black "Curt von Bardeleben"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "C54"]
[EventDate "1895.08.05"]
[PlyCount "48"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d4 exd4 6.cxd4 Bb4+ 7.Nc3 d5 8.exd5 Nxd5 9.O-O Be6 10.Bg5 Be7 11.Bxd5 Bxd5 12.Nxd5 Qxd5 13.Bxe7 Nxe7 14.Re1 f6 15.Qe2 Qd7 16.Rac1 c6 17.d5 cxd5 18.Nd4 Kf7 19.Ne6 Rhc8 20.Qg4 g6 21.Ng5+ Ke8 22.Rxe7+ Kf8 23.Rf7+ Kg8 24.Rg7+ Kh8 25.Rxh7+ 

    [Event "FICS rated standard game (FICS, San Jose"]
    [Site "California USA)"]
    [Date "2009.12.09"]
    [Round "?"]
    [White "Damo"]
    [Black "Dalvero"]
    [Result "0-1"]
    [PlyCount "16"]
    [WhiteElo "1565"]
    [BlackElo "1465"]

    1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. Nc3 d6 5. h3 Nf6 6. Ng5 O-O 7. d3 Nd4 8. Bd2
    Be6 0-1 {White forfeits by disconnection}
```

Comment: `\A\[Event.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[Event).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/aiEmsk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lookaheads are supported, you could match `[Event` at the start of the string `\A` followed by matching all the lines that do not start with `[Event` using a negative lookahead in a repeating group.

If `\A` is not supported, use `^` and the value is the first match.

```
\A\[Event.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[Event).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWxJ8f/1)

Comment: This works perfectly for the question I asked, I then edited the post to give an outlier situation that this doesn't work for, but since doing that edit, I realised if I simply add a space to your solution, it solves the problem. So `\A\[Event.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[Event ).*)*` Does the trick. Many thanks!